# Connect to remote Docker container in VS Code

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, remote-access

I'm trying to connect to a remote Docker container via Remote-SSH/Remote-Container/Docker extension on VS Code. I've tried the following options, but none of them worked as expected:

1. Connect to remote container using Docker context with Docker extension

I created a Docker context that allows me to connect to the remote machine. I was able to connect to the shell of the container in terminal, but I wasn't able to use the Docker extension. It says `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`. I've tried multiple settings for docker.host option but wasn't able to get any of them working. Since I'm able to connect to it via terminal, the connection should not be a problem.

2. Connect to the remote machine using Remote-SSH extension and attach VS Code to the docker container with Docker extension

When I start the container without mounting volumes, this option worked well. However, when I try to mount a volume, the following error occurred:

```
[6774 ms] /bin/sh: 22: cannot create /home/jovyan/.gitconfig: Permission denied
[6774 ms] Exit code 2
[6778 ms] Command in container failed: # Copy /my/local/directory/.gitconfig to /home/jovyan/.gitconfig
(dd iflag=fullblock bs=8192 count=0 2>/dev/null; dd iflag=fullblock bs=211 count=1 2>/dev/null) >/home/jovyan/.gitconfig
```

Note that in the second case, even though attaching VS Code failed, I was able to use the terminal and port forwarding, which means that the container is running correctly.

Comment: This sounds like something I'd very much like to use with our students. Were you able to figure out how to get this fully working?